# Why is numeric property access 100x slower?

Tags: javascript, performance, properties

During testing a memory mapped vector wrapper class, it became obvious that the same property accessor code attached to numeric properties is at least 100x slower than if attached to non-numeric properties:

```js
class Vec2 {
    constructor(buf, off) {
        this.buf = new Float32Array(buf, off, 2);
    }
    get x() {
        return this.buf[0];
    }
    get y() {
        return this.buf[1];
    }
    set x(x) {
        this.buf[0] = x;
    }
    set y(y) {
        this.buf[1] = y;
    }
    get "0"() {
        return this.buf[0];
    }
    get "1"() {
        return this.buf[1];
    }
    set "0"(x) {
        this.buf[0] = x;
    }
    set "1"(y) {
        this.buf[1] = y;
    }
}
```

```js
const bench = require("@thi.ng/bench").bench;
const tx = require("@thi.ng/transducers");

const N = 10000;
const buf = new Float32Array(N * 2).fill(1);
const pts = [...tx.map((i) => new Vec2(buf.buffer, i * 8), tx.range(N))];

const updateXY = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pts[i].x += 1;
        pts[i].y += 2;
    }
};

const update01 = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pts[i]["0"] += 1;
        pts[i]["1"] += 2;
    }
};

bench(updateXY, 1000);
// 58ms

bench(update01, 1000);
// 6604ms
```

Could anyone care to explain possible reasons? For this specific case here, a possible workaround is extending the class from `Float32Array`, which *does* make a noticeable difference (both versions now ~70ms), but my question is more general...

```js
class Vec2 extends Float32Array {
    constructor(buf, off) {
        super(buf, off, 2);
    }

    get x() {
        return this[0];
    }

    get y() {
        return this[1];
    }

    set x(x) {
        this[0] = x;
    }

    set y(y) {
        this[1] = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: What environment is this in? Also, are you re-using the same array/objects between the two tests?

Comment: Imho, the relevant questions are the following: Is the benchmark done properly, is this really the case in this scenario? Are you sure this behavior happens consistently (even if you change the code around a bit)? Does it matter for your application? Subjectively speaking, i have the feeling, that for 99% of these benchmark questions, one of these should be answered with "no". In almost all cases, it's not worth investigating, and getting to the bottom of this can prove absurdly difficult.

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, sorry forgot to mention env is: MBP2016, node 12.10.0

Comment: @ASDFGerte I'd say in this case this matters a lot, e.g. when batch processing geometry (say a large mesh with 100-200k vertices). I've got a vectors library which works with any array-like vector type, and therefore uses numeric index accessors, so the difference here is massive...

Comment: The problem is, that "measuring execution time with some weird timer" is often influenced by very small and unexpected details. I can give an example of c++ benchmarking, where simply changing the linux username caused a 40% performance increase. Making sure, that this "benchmark" actually gives no unfair advantage to either case, no weird detail was omitted, and the same can be observed in a non-sterile setup (which is the important case), is very difficult. What i am saying is, my view on this is usually "lets hope the people writing the engine knew what they were doing, better than me".

Comment: @ASDFGerte Completely agree w/ you on the dangers of micro-benchmarking, but if one version is off >2 orders of magnitude, then this IMHO points to a real difference in the underlying impl., rather than some timer subtleties or isolated usage patterns. As for the "non-sterile" setup, I've actually noticed the issue in a real-world use case, but the code above is a MVE and exhibits fundamentally the same issue/behavior, at least in Node/V8. Also, I'm not so much interested here in how to improve it, but would like to understand the reasons for a likely different treatment of numeric properties.

Comment: This is probably related to javascript engine fast indicies optimizations. I reproduced similar results on V8 and SpiderMonkey and it led me to [this blog post](https://v8.dev/blog/fast-properties). I can imagine that internal Hidden Class struct lookup/set is faster than Hidden Class array lookup/set for given index. Also  there is internal casting from str to int. When you compare set for {"0": 0} vs {0: 0}, there is huge performance difference.